# Does Raspberry Pi 2 support RTOS?

Tags: real-time, xenomai

did somone have the knowdlege is new Raspberry Pi 2 is compatibile with Xenomai RTOS?

In old version (Raspberry 1) that was a path which make berry to work with Xenomai.
I was started reading about second version about possibility to port old application written for Raspberry 1 with Xenomai to v.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like Xenomai is meant to be [source built](http://xenomai.org/installing-xenomai-3-x/).  So you should be able to do this.

Someone evidently has [precompiled binaries](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=74686) for the regular pi.  The only issue with this will be the kernel: the old armv6 userland will work on the pi 2, but you still need a different kernel for it.

But while armv6 code will run on the pi 2, [as noted here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=98428) (see "How much faster is it?"), if you want to realize the full potential of the new cores, you need stuff that was compiled for armv7 (which will not run on the old pi).

You probably want to cross-compile, since the pi 2 is still really slow compared to a normal desktop.  Fortunately, ready made x86 -> armv7 tool chains are much easier to find than armv6 ones.

If the instructions on the Xenomai site aren't enough, here's a [decent looking guide](http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?RaspbianXenomaiBuild) to building a Xenomai system with a raspbian userspace.  Note again though that this means using slower armv6 user land binaries (there is no armv7 raspbian currently, just the armv6 one with an armv7 kernel) -- however it might provide a simple starting point for you to get a kernel running, and then you can tackle building the userland properly as a second stage.